# How to get value from multiple drop down fields with the same name

Tags: php, magento, select

I have added 5 drop down fields in my form with the same name. These field will be displayed based on selected country's radio button.I have 5 radio buttons named as "**USA,INDIA,UK,EURO,AUS**".

If i select USA, 1st drop down contains US sizes, will be displayed.
If i select INDIA,2nd drop down contains INDIAN sizes, will be displayed.

All are working Good. Now i have an issue with store that value to my DB in magento. When i submit the form, 5th drop down field(**EURO sizes**) value only saved.

If i select size other than EURO,I got an empty value. If i select Euro size, I got correct value.I hope you understand my problem. Please guide me to solve mine issue guys!

Comment: Using the same name for form fields is a really bad practice.
Why should you do such thing?

Comment: because any one of size only will chose by customer from those 5 countries.i have **selectsize** field for to store that selected size.If i'll use different name for those drop down fields, i need to create 4 more field for to save that single value. I have no idea to achieve this task.so only i have used  same name!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `disabled` attribute to other drop-downs when you show the selected one. This way the browser will ignore the disabled ones.

Or, you could append `[]` to your drop-downs' name, like this:

```
<select name="name[]"> ... </select>
```

This way you will get an array in the request variable, then you can decide which to use in the array according to your radio button value.